# WinRT C# - A listbox with dropdown style

Tags: c#, combobox, listbox, styles, windows-runtime

I would like to make a multiple selection with a combobox, but I think it's not easy. It's why I would like to use a Listbox with a dropdown style like a combobox.

Do you have any ideas how to do this ? (A multiselection on a combobox or a dropdown style on a listbox).

Thanks for your time,

Regards.